# Group homomorphism between multiplicative groups of rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, group-homomorphism, continuous-homomorphisms

My concrete example is that the determinant is a group homomorphism between $GL(n, \mathbb{C})$ and the non-zero complex numbers. But we know that $GL(n, \mathbb{C}) = M(n, \mathbb{C})^{\times}$ is the multiplicative group of all $n\times n$ linear transformations $M(n, \mathbb{C})$ and the non-zero complex numbers $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$ is the multiplicative group of the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$. So we have

$\text{det}:M(n, \mathbb{C})^{\times} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{\times}$

is a homomorphism. But $\text{det}$, defined or continuously extened over all of $M(n, \mathbb{C})$ also has the property that it maps non-invertible elements of $M(n, \mathbb{C})$ to 0, the non-invertible element of $\mathbb{C}$.

Can this idea be generalized? Suppose $A$ and $B$ are rings and we have a homomorphism $\phi$

$$
\phi:A^{\times} \rightarrow B^{\times}
$$

Is it true that we can continuously extend $\phi$ to $A$ by $\tilde{\phi}$ and that when we do so we will find something like $\tilde{\phi}(A-A^{\times})\subset B-B^{\times}$? If not are there some additional conditions that make something like this true?

Maybe topology is required so the notion of continuity makes sense...?

Comment: Continuously extension does not make sense. Are $A, B$ both topological ring?

Comment: @Nightflight I don't know... I may not know enough to ask the question... but I'm trying to ask a question about a generalization of the concept that I noted for $\text{det}$. I don't know if continuity is important, maybe another type of "structure-preserving" extension of $\phi$ would do. If continuity is what is needed then yes $A$ and $B$ can be topological rings.

Comment: I would forget about addition and focus on multiplication. I would ask the question: if $M,N$ are monoids and $M^\times, N^\times$ the submonoids of invertible elements of $M,N$, respectively, and if we are given a homomorphism $\varphi: M^\times \to N^\times$, is it possible to extend $\varphi$ to a homomorphism $M \to N$? I don't know the answer to this, I'm just commenting something quick that comes to mind.

Comment: @joeb yes I thought about phrasing it in terms of monoids originally. Your comment is in fact in line with what I was probably intending. Thanks for the insight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extension by zero is always possible: the set of non-invertible elements of a ring form a two-sided ideal, so defining $\tilde{\phi}: A\to B$ by letting $\tilde{\phi}|_{A^\times} = \phi$ and $\tilde{\phi}_{A \setminus A^\times} = 0$ is a homomorphism. A more interesting question might be when this is the only such extension. The answer is not always, since the identity map on $A^\times$ can be extended to the identity map on $A$.

It's not always true that in such an extension the non-invertible elements must be sent to non-invertible elements; consider the extension of $\mathbb{Z}^\times \hookrightarrow \mathbb{Q}^\times$ to $\mathbb{Z} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{Q}$, or similar examples involving localization.

Comment: A two-sided monoid ideal, that is. Ring-theoretically, the non-invertible elements need not be preserved under addition.

Comment: I wonder if topology + continuity helps towards making the extension unique.